# Nothing returned while scraping website using splash

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to splash so I have this question : I tried to scrape this website using splash: https://iboard.ssi.com.vn/bang-gia/vn30. the response is 200 but when i included my xpath it returned nothing. Here is my code : ( I already changed download middleware )

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class VndirectScrapeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'vndirect_scrape'
    allowed_domains = ['iboard.ssi.com.vn']
    start_urls = ['https://iboard.ssi.com.vn/bang-gia/vn30']
    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(url=self.start_urls[0],callback=self.parse,args={'wait': '5'},endpoint='render.html')
    def parse(self, response):
        name = response.xpath('//tr[@id="BID"]/@id')
        yield {'name':name}`
```

Can anyone help me on this ? Much appreciation

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if scrapy supports that but the page you are visiting is a single page application. Which means the first request of the page only have related clientside libraries. css, js files. The rest of the data coming with async request. If scrapy supports you need to wait until certain elements are loaded.

Comment: thank you very much for your quick response. As I googled, splash does support crawling a SPA . Can you make it more clear on the part " you need to wait until certain elements for its loading " (how to identify that certain elements and set up for a delay for that elements to be loaded .. ) as i tried to change time waited from 5 to 20,30 but things did not work.

Comment: oh and besides, when I loaded through http://localhost:8050/, the returned html is not much